# Set custom environment variables for win 32 executable using powershell / batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have an old VB.NET application from 2008 that uses **Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData** to store it's settings and data. This works perfectly fine when a user uses the application from a windows PC. However, we are being asked to move this application to Remote Desktop Services, which causes the application to malfunction when >1 person uses the application.

What I would like to do is write a script (powershell / batch file) that sets the **CommonApplicationData** 
 environment variable to a value specified in the batch file so that RDS users can run this.

Something along the lines of this..

```
Set CommonApplicationData = 'C:\..\..\%username%\MySessionThatIsUniqueToMe'
OldProgramFrom2008.exe
```

Thank-you in advance.

EDIT: Powershell looks like the way to go ?
[image]

Comment: Your approach should work but you need to remove the spaces around `=`, use double quotes `"` and possibly escape the backslashes.

Comment: What doesn't work well with your above script? Apart from the fact that the command should be written as `set CommonApplicationData=C:\..\..\%username%\MySessionThatIsUniqueToMe`. See [link](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: It's the inbuilt OS level CommonApplicationData that needs to be changed